# Two Consecutive Segol's at End: When They Change To Kamatz & When Not

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I used to think it was a hard fast rule that when a word ends in two consecutive segols such as: אֶרֶץ (or כסף) it will change the first Segol to a Kamatz as in אָרֶץ.  However, it was pointed out to me in this past week's parasha that the word תֶּבֶן is never written as תָּבֶן.  Same with many other words, such as קֶדֶם.  So the question is when does this rule apply and when not?
[image]

Comment: What's a grammar rule that doesn't have exceptions?

Comment: @msh210 that question asks why it happens, this one asks when it happens (presumably this could be answered by a list of words, whereas the other one couldn't)